# Keep trying to buffer/reconnect

Tags: android

I have a small radio app, I'm trying to get it to keep trying to reconnect/buffer my stream forever without quiting... not sure how I can loop this, but this is my buffering code. Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
public void prepare() {
    /* ------Station- buffering-------- */
    isPreparingStarted = true;
            setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_THREE));
            showNotification();
            try {
                if (getCurrentStationType().equals(SIGNAL_AAC))
                    multiPlayer.playAsync(StationURL());
                else {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(StationURL());
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stop();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stop();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stop();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                stop();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can set error listener on MediaPlayer? `mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener`

Comment: sorry, extremely dummy here... how do i do that?